# How to play QAudioBuffer by QIODevice?

Tags: qt, audio, streaming

I want to make an audio streaming program (like phone) using the `QMediaPlayer`, `QAudioProbe` and `QAudioOutput` classes in Qt 5.3.0 MSVC2012 OpenGL 32bit.

This is my code:

```
musicPlayer     = new QMediaPlayer();
musicProbe      = new QAudioProbe();

musicProbe->setSource(musicPlayer);

connect(musicProbe, SIGNAL(audioBufferProbed(QAudioBuffer)),
        this, SLOT(slotGetMusicData(QAudioBuffer)));
```

If audio data probed, the slot is actived.

```
void MusicPlayer::slotGetMusicData(QAudioBuffer musicBuffer)
{
    /*QAudioBuffer to QByteArray*/
    *musicDataBuffer = musicDataBuffer->fromRawData((char *)musicBuffer.data(),
                                                     ,musicBuffer.byteCount());
    /*Send Music Data*/
    musicSocket->sendMudicData(*musicDataBuffer);
    qDebug("send complete");
}
```

Using a socket, I send the data to another program.

The other program plays the music received.

```
QAudioOutput *audioOutput = new QAudioOutput(format, this);
QIoDevice *audioDevice = audioOutput->start();
```

and then, data received this slot is actived.

```
void BgmSocket::slotPlayBgm(QByteArray data)    
{
    audioDevice->write(data.data(), data.size());
}
```

The audio is playing well, but the sounds have a lot of static (pause sound).

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a different frequency between the network and the playback buffer.

I solved this problem by creating a buffer with double buffering.